# Why 3000 in artist's name?

Tags: names

A lot of artists well known or not, have the prefix `3000` in their name. For example `Andre 3000`, Mr Oizo who's also known as `oizo3000` and many others, especially in electronic music.

I've read [an article](http://www.highsnobiety.com/2015/06/04/10-biggest-hip-hop-stars-got-rap-names/) about Andre3000's name origin, it explains why he changed his artist's name, but not why he chose this one.

Does anywhone know why 3000 and where it comes from ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I was a kid in the 70's the year 2000 was a cliché for anything futuristic   or that wanted to be seen as ahead of it's time. Innumerable books, cartoons, movies, tv shows and yes, a few bands too, had 2000 in the name.

I suppose 3000 is the new futuristic year of choice...

Comment: Sounds like supposition rather than an actual answer. It would be better to find some factual evidence (e.g. Artist interview) as to why it was chosen.

Comment: You're right Roger, it is a supposition (I said so myself), but a plausible one, I'd say. I only entered it as an answer and not as comment as the OP refers to "many others", so there seems to be a common thread of sorts. But it may be something more specific to the EDM scene or any other reason, I don't have any evidence one way or the other.

Comment: It is an good answer. An answer is not necessary THE answer, it can be incomplete, as far as it answers the question in a way, it has to be an answer. Back to subject, that's the most obvious supposition. I guess 3000 is not as "obvious" as the year 2000 was in the 80's 90's, but to my mind, the idea of "future" is definitely there !

Comment: I think this is correct.  Compare this memorable lyric from *Boom Boom Pow* - "I'm so 3008, you so 2000 and late."